# Задача java на алгоритмы сортировки

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/* Задача по алгоритмам
Задача: Пользователь вводит с клавиатуры список слов (и чисел). Слова вывести в возрастающем порядке, числа - в убывающем.
Пример ввода:
Вишня
1
Боб
3
Яблоко
2
0
Арбуз
Пример вывода:
Арбуз
3
Боб
2
Вишня
1
0
Яблоко
*/

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (true)
        {
            String s = reader.readLine();
            if (s.isEmpty()) break;
            list.add(s);
        }

        String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        sort(array);

        for (String x : array)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

    public static void sort(String[] array)
    {
        //напишите тут ваш код
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Boolean> bools = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String a : array)
        {
            if (isNumber(a))
            {
                bools.add(true);
                numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(a));
            }
            else
            {
                bools.add(false);
                words.add(a);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < words.size() - i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (isGreaterThan(words.get(j + 1), words.get(j)))
                {
                    String change = words.get(j + 1);
                    words.set(j + 1, words.get(j));
                    words.set(j, words.get(j + 1));
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.size() - i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (numbers.get(j) < numbers.get(j + 1))
                {
                    int change = numbers.get(j);
                    numbers.set(j, numbers.get(j + 1));
                    numbers.set(j + 1, change);
                }
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0, ii = 0, check = 0; check < array.length; )
        {
            if (bools.get(i))
            {
                array[check] = String.valueOf(numbers.get(i));
                i++;
                check++;
            }
            if (!(bools.get(ii)))
            {
                array[check] = words.get(ii);
                ii++;
                check++;
            }
        }
    }

    //Метод для сравнения строк: 'а' больше чем 'b'
    public static boolean isGreaterThan(String a, String b)
    {
        return a.compareTo(b) > 0;
    }


    //строка - это на самом деле число?
    public static boolean isNumber(String s)
    {
        if (s.length() == 0) return false;

        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        {
            char c = chars[i];
            if ((i != 0 && c == '-') //есть '-' внутри строки
                    || (!Character.isDigit(c) && c != '-') ) // не цифра и не начинается с '-'
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Вот, собственно, задача. Проблема в том, что у меня почему-то идет ввод без остановки, даже когда я ввожу пустую строку. Так и не нашел в коде проблемы, прошу помочь) И да, не пишите, почему я не сортировал готовыми методами, так задачу не берет.

Comment: и да, знаю что можно было в 1 цикле отсортировать, я повторил, чтобы запомнить алгоритм пурырьковой сортировки.

Comment: Для начала хотя бы посмотрите на какой строчке indexOutOfBoundsException возникает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас неверный алгоритм слияния.

Вы проверяете `bools.get(i)`, то есть, индекс среди строк. Если, например, `bools.get(i)` содержит `false`, вы никогда не увеличите `i`, и пройдёте весь цикл, пытаясь прочитать значения из `words` (а там их вполне может быть меньше, чем общая длина исходного контейнера `array.length`).

Нужно проверять общий индекс, в вашем случае это просто `i + ii`.

Кроме того, проверка `i < array.length - 1 && ii < array.length - 1` неправильная. Нужно либо `i < numbers.length || ii < words.length`, либо `i + ii < array.length`.

(Возможно, есть и другие ошибки, трассируйте.)

Comment: изменил код на новый, появилась странная ошибка, ввод идет вечно, хотя когда ввожу пустую строку, должно останавливаться, не менял ничего там.

Comment: @Maxgmer: Ну попробуйте оттрассировать, гляньте, почему `s.isEmpty()` не выполняется.

Comment: Блин, тут отладчик работает сложнее, чем в паскале, как отлаживать проги в Intellij IDEA? Как вообще перемещаться по шагам, есть ли какой-либо отчет о выполнении программы?

Comment: @Maxgmer: Это не помогает: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/debugging.html?